# IAM users to restrict creating instances in a region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I want to create a IAM group and attach a policy so that any users who will be added to that group can only launch resources in `ap-south` region. How to create such a policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'user-level setting' to restrict usage to a region.

Instead, any existing permissions that are being granted to the user **need to be modified** to specifically limit those permissions to the region.

If you have any existing policies that grant the user permission to launch resources, you will need to **change those policies to include a condition** such as:

```json
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": "eu-central-1"
                }
            }
```

See: [Easier way to control access to AWS regions using IAM policies | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easier-way-to-control-access-to-aws-regions-using-iam-policies/)